# how to check internet connection in c#

Tags: c#, silverlight

I created silverlight project.That is dashboard information project.
I created two types of dashboard, One is **Dashboard.Xaml** another one is **Dashboard.Html**.

Now requirement is If internet connection available means we show **Dashboard.Html** other wise if
internet connection is not available means we show **Dashboard.Xaml**

How to check Internet connection is connected or not connected in c#?

How to trigger automatically internet is Connected means-**Dashboard.Html** or not-connected means-**Dashboard.Xaml**?

Please Help Me...

Comment: You can read the marked answer [here][1]. It's that you looking for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159036/check-internet-connection-in-silverlight

Comment: [how-do-i-check-for-a-network-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520347/how-do-i-check-for-a-network-connection)

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
bool IsNetIn= NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ping valid address on the internet.

```
public bool PingHost(string nameOrAddress)
    {
        PingReply reply;
        using (var pinger = new Ping())
        {
            reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress);
        }

        bool pingable=false;
        if (reply != null) pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;


        return pingable;
    }
```